# FFMPEG makes my website DOWN while converting video

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04, cpu

I have an `upload.php` script to upload & convert videos where I use FFMPEG. *(LAMP Ubuntu 16.04)*

However as soon as FFMPEG starts to convert the video, the all website becomes unresponsive so I guess FFMPEG uses all my CPU.

Here is the 3 lines I use to convert source video:

```
* Check format, size, ect..

shell_exec('ffmpeg -i '.$temp_path.' -r 1/1 '.$path_jpeg.'');
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i '.$temp_path.' -f webm -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -acodec libvorbis '.$path_webm.' -hide_banner');
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i '.$temp_path.' -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -c:a copy '.$path_mp4.' -hide_banner');

* Add video data to DB
```

Is there anyway to limit CPU ressources for FFMPEG while converting videos?

Thanks

EDIT :

I tried to use `-threads 1` without success

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i '.$temp_path.' -f webm -c:v libvpx -threads 1 -b:v 1M -acodec libvorbis '.$path_webm.' -hide_banner');
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i '.$temp_path.' -c:v libx264 -threads 1 -preset veryfast -c:a copy '.$path_mp4.' -hide_banner');
```

I tried to use `nice -n 15` without success as well

```
shell_exec('nice -n 15 ffmpeg -i '.$temp_path.' -f webm -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -acodec libvorbis '.$path_webm.' -hide_banner');
shell_exec('nice -n 15 ffmpeg -i '.$temp_path.' -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -c:a copy '.$path_mp4.' -hide_banner');
```

FFMPEG is still eating 100% of my CPU while converting

[image]

Comment: You can limit encoding threads e.g. `-threads 1`. Add it after the encoder name.

Comment: Seems likely you're also wide open to executing arbitrary code on your machine.  You **must** escape those variables for use with `shell_exec()`!!

Comment: @Gyan I tried your method without success (I edited my thread, you can check)

Comment: It's using one core fully. Not all cores.

Comment: @Gyan what could be the reason of the website black out considering I have 
6 vCPUs on my VPS?

Answer (score 1):

This happened because you didn't send FFMPEG process to background. you can do this by using nohup.

```
shell_exec("nohup ffmpeg (...)  > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always execute FFmpeg with `nice`.  Something like this...

```
shell_exec('nice -n 15 ffmpeg...
```

Note that your system may actually be starved for some other resource, like disk I/O.  Use `top` to find out.

Comment: I tried your method without success (I edited my thread, you can check)

Comment: @casusbelli You might need a higher nice value.  Also, it's possible that MySQL is using the useful amount of CPU and is blocked on I/O.  The fact that it's getting 25% is encouraging.  Is there a reason you have to run your database and FFmpeg on the same system, anyway?